# How to reset Windows 10 installation without losing grub

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub

Is there a way to reset windows 10 installation without affecting other oses? I have one windows 10, and two linuxes (Ubuntu 20.04 and 16.04). I was planning on using windows recovery option->remove everything, but I've read that win10 will overwrite the bootloader. Is there a way to prevent this? I'm using uefi, oses are on the same drive.

EDIT: For anyone wondering, in my case reset option did not affect the grub

Comment: You are better of using the Reset feature from within Windows.  Are you able to link to what you have read? In the worst case, Grub will still exist, but you will have to reconfigure your system to use it instead of the Windows Bootloader (which is an extremely simple task).

Comment: Yes, as I've pointed out, I was going to use  "recovery option->remove everything" within windows. You mean something like  [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) will be enough? As for the links, [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine)

Comment: Backup the EFI System Partition using any live Linux distro, either manually (it's FAT32), with Clonezilla, dd or whatever. Windows may change default boot entry back to its bootloader, but probably won't remove GRUB. It's a matter of a single BIOS setup change to make GRUB the default again. But in case Windows would remove GRUB, just restore EFI System Partition and you'll be able to change the default back to GRUB.

Comment: The Windows Reset option only makes modifications to the Windows partition.  As I pointed out the worst case is you will have to reconfigure your system to use Grub.  You should of course take the proper precautions in the event something unexpected happens